# Adding my free Google Drive storage to my Gmail storage

Tags: gmail, google-drive, online-storage

I am running out of storage in my Gmail account. However, I have 5GB of free space on my Google Drive.

Is there a way I can store some of my emails (not only their attachments, but the complete email) in my Google Drive?

Another viable solution would be to “add” the storage that I have on my Google Drive to the one on my Gmail account.

Is this possible?

Comment: I got +5GB for GMail when I signed up to GDrive, so I'm now at 10.1GB max. Do you need even more?

Comment: [This question is asking the opposite](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/55/is-there-any-way-to-use-gmail-storage-in-other-google-services).

Answer (score 5):

Just announced:

[Bringing it all together: 15 GB now shared between Drive, Gmail, and Google+ Photos](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2013/05/bringing-it-all-together-15-gb-now.html)

> With this new combined storage space, you won’t have to worry about how much you’re storing and where. For example, maybe you’re a heavy Gmail user but light on photos, or perhaps you were bumping up against your Drive storage limit but were only using 2 GB in Gmail. Now it doesn’t matter, because you can use your storage the way you want.

So, it looks like you only need to wait until they roll this out to you, which will probably be within the next few weeks.